# Can I put a drawing in tikz in margin in book style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, book-design, marginpar

Is it possible to put my graph (tikz) instead of the text in the margin on page 7??

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{marginnote,geometry,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\geometry{innermargin=70pt,top=125pt,
    textwidth=345pt,textheight=598pt,
    marginparwidth=135pt,marginparsep=17pt,
    heightrounded}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indholdsfortegnelse}

\title{Differentialregning}
\author{Jakob Blom Kruse}
\date{2021}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

% Fjerne header på inholdsfortegnelsen
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\else
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fi
\chapter{Integralregning}
\section{Introduction}
Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   
\newpage
asæmsdv\\
ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v
\marginpar{Min tekst i margin}
\chapter{Differentialregning}
\section{Sektion 2}
Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så slæknv ks vlks væks vlks væskv kslv sv lksv lskv. smv .sm vksæ vms. vms vsm,,v sm,d vsm,dv s,m vs,md vs,mv
\marginpar{En højre margisdfv kæ svxk sf sdfb dsbf dsfb dsbsdfb  sdfb dsfb  dsb dfb db dfb dbf dfb db n}
 kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\
dgbc\\
aæbcj\\
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0,45\textwidth}\centering
        %\vspace{1cm}
        \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.55,0.55,0.9}
        \definecolor{gitter}{rgb}{0.65,0.65,0.65}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm] 
            \draw [color=gitter, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] (-5,-1) grid (5,10);  % Grid område
            \draw[->,color=black, line width=1pt] (-5,0) -- (5,0);    %X-akse
            \draw[color=black] (4.8,0.05) node [anchor=west] {\fontsize{7}{7} \text{x}}; %Aksenanvn
            \draw[->,color=black, line width=1pt] (0,-1) -- (0,10);    %Y-akse
            \draw[color=black] (-0.1,10.9) node [anchor=north] {\fontsize{7}{7} \text{y}}; % Aksenavn
        
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\subsection{Prøve på en undersektion}

aeøfm

\section{Sektion 3}
\newpage    
\section{Afslutning}
Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try just putting the `tikzpicture` in a `\marginpar`?

Comment: BYW, I noticed you loaded the marginnote package.  While putting a tikzpicture in \marginpar works fine (tried it), \marginnote uses TikZ so you may need to use a savebox to avoild putting a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: Thank you both, now it works for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `textpos` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package from this documentation with a `\begin{textblock}{7}(10.1,8.2)....\end{textblock}` for your specific graph, you can put it to the right. Obviously the position of the image is correlated to the coordinates `(10.1,8.2)` which will need to be changed in relation to the text you have above the image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{marginnote,geometry,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\geometry{innermargin=70pt,top=125pt,
    textwidth=345pt,textheight=598pt,
    marginparwidth=135pt,marginparsep=17pt,
    heightrounded}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indholdsfortegnelse}

\title{Differentialregning}
\author{Jakob Blom Kruse}
\date{2021}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

% Fjerne header på inholdsfortegnelsen
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\else
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fi
\chapter{Integralregning}
\section{Introduction}
Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   
\newpage
asæmsdv\\
ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v
\marginpar{Min tekst i margin}
\chapter{Differentialregning}
\section{Sektion 2}
Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så slæknv ks vlks væks vlks væskv kslv sv lksv lskv. smv .sm vksæ vms. vms vsm,,v sm,d vsm,dv s,m vs,md vs,mv
\marginpar{En højre margisdfv kæ svxk sf sdfb dsbf dsfb dsbsdfb  sdfb dsfb  dsb dfb db dfb dbf dfb db n}
 kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\
dgbc\\
aæbcj\\

\begin{textblock}{7}(10.1,8.2)
\centering
        %\vspace{1cm}
        \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.55,0.55,0.9}
        \definecolor{gitter}{rgb}{0.65,0.65,0.65}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm] 
            \draw [color=gitter, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] (-5,-1) grid (5,10);  % Grid område
            \draw[->,color=black, line width=1pt] (-5,0) -- (5,0);    %X-akse
            \draw[color=black] (4.8,0.05) node [anchor=west] {\fontsize{7}{7} \text{x}}; %Aksenanvn
            \draw[->,color=black, line width=1pt] (0,-1) -- (0,10);    %Y-akse
            \draw[color=black] (-0.1,10.9) node [anchor=north] {\fontsize{7}{7} \text{y}}; % Aksenavn
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock}



\subsection{Prøve på en undersektion}

aeøfm

\section{Sektion 3}
\newpage    
\section{Afslutning}
Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]